# Spotify snap broken with Nvidia driver 396.24.02

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, snap, spotify

Upgraded my Nvidia driver just now from 396.24.0 to 396.24.02, rebooted, and Spotify no longer works. It opens a window but never draws anything but a black screen.

```
cxf@PC:~$ snap run spotify
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[0604/185738.869585:ERROR:gl_context_glx.cc(227)] Couldn't make context current with X drawable.
[0604/185738.869619:ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(62)] gl::GLContext::MakeCurrent() failed
[0604/185746.603499:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(120)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

[image: Spotify black screen.]

Comment: You'll have to wait until the snap is updated or use the .deb version which works fine (spotify-client  1:1.0.77.338.g758ebd78-41

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Until fixed snaps are available, you can start spotify without GPU accelerated graphics

```
# snap run spotify --disable-gpu
```

Comment: This doesn’t work anymore.

Comment: Luckily it's also not needed anymore. Tested with nvidia driver version 430.50 and just installing the snap and using it.
Can't tell about the legacy tree (version 340) für older nvidia cards tho.

Comment: For me it did not work, but the flatpak version worked. I am using 430.50 as well.